# Combinations with repetitions, is my logic correct?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Fifty identical chocolate bars are to be distributed among $8$ children. If the oldest three must have a total of $10$ bars and the youngest three must have at least $3$ each. In how many ways can the bars be distributed?

Oldest 3 children need 10 bars: $\binom{10+3-1}{3} = \binom{12}{3}= 220 $

Youngest 3 children need 9 or more (3 each) = $\binom{9+3-1}{3} = 165$

$31$ bars are left to distribute to the youngest children and the remaining 2 children: $\binom{31+5-1}{5} = 324,632$

So there would be a total of $325017$ ways to distribute with the above restrictions.

Comment: You need to multiply these together, not add them.  Further, the condition that the youngest three need at least 3 each... just give them three each.  You don't need to count how many ways to do this step as there is just one way to do it.

Comment: Could you please give some more info about the following?
You write "If the oldest three must have a total of 10 bars ...". Interpretation 1: The three oldest children must have a sum total of $10$ bars (so these three have altogether $10$ bars). Interpretation 2: Each of these three oldest children must have $10$ (so these three have altogether $30$ bars.)

Comment: @trancelocation Interpretation 1..the oldest three should have a total sum of 10 bars.

Comment: Ah. And what do you mean by a "way" of distributing. For example, if we number the three youngest children by 1,2,3, then 123123123... and 111222333... could be two different ways of distributing three bars to each but the result would be the same. Do you distinguish between these ways or is only the result of a way of distribution relevant?

Comment: Referring to my last question:
If only the different possible resulting distributions are of interest, then Ross Millikan's answer is the corresponding one.

Answer (score 4):

You are reading the problem to say the oldest three must share exactly $10$, not at least $10$, which makes sense to me.  For the younger three you can just give them three each and distribute the other $41$.  The ten to the oldest three can be distributed in ${10+3-1\choose 3-1}=66$ ways.  We should multiply that by the number of ways to distribute the other $31$ among five people, which is ${31+5-1 \choose 5-1}=52360$  The final count is $66 \cdot 52360=3455760$